# Why we can apply conditional logistic regression to model the effect of air pollution?

Tags: r, time-series, logistic, cox-model, case-control-study

In a book called 'Analysing Seasonal Health Data', the time series dataset - CVDdaily was expanded by 'casecross' function,

```
casecross(cvd~o3mean+tmpd
          +Mon+Tue+Wed+Thu+Fri+Sat,data=CVDdaily,
          stratalength=28,exclusion=6)
```

and I cannot understand why we need to expand the dataset in order to fit the conditional logistic regression, please explain it.

[image]

This is the original dataset(CVDdaily) from library(season)

After using casecross function to expand the dataset:

the dataset became:

[image]

Why the function adds 22 rows to every dates and why we need 'case' and 'timex' column?

Also, why we can use the above data with only 'True'(case = 1) case?

---

Update:

I want to ask one more question:
why we add 22 rows without knowing whether ***people admitted to hospital in case days*** would go to hospital again in control days or not?

Comment: This question is hard to understand with so little context. If you're discussing a specific paper or other publication, you should cite the article and reproduce the key parts to understand what you are asking about. Please [edit] to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of comparing the exposure for people who are cases and not cases, the case-crossover design compares exposure for a person at the time they had an event with their exposures at other times when they didn't have an event.

In a matched case-control design, the conditional likelihood conditions on the number of events in a case and their matched controls (at a specific point in time). In a case-crossover design, you condition on the number of events at a case time and a set of control times, for a specific person.

The original idea was that this would just give conditional logistic regression.  In your example, the control times are the past 28 days except for the past 6 days -- which adds up to 22. You start off with the case records, and you end up with an extra 22 control records for each of them.  You need to know the exposure for these 22 extra records, but it's air pollution. It's public. The government measures it and tells you.

So, for each case you have a matched set of 22 control times and you do conditional logistic regression, estimating which $\beta$ best matches the relationship between exposure and being an event.

This is all not *quite* true, though it is how the approach was derived. [My first involvement](https://doi.org/10.1002/1099-095X(200011/12)11:6%3C689::AID-ENV439%3E3.0.CO;2-N) with case-crossover designs in air pollution was to point out that the so-called conditional likelihood is not actually a conditional likelihood. Fortunately, maximising the 'conditional likelihood' does give pretty reasonable estimates, even though you can do better.

Comment: Sorry for asking something stupid: why we need extra 22 control records if we do not know whether hospitalized people(assuming that there are no death cases) in case day will go to the hospital again or not...? I am struggling at this point...

Comment: The control days are usually in the past, when you *know* the person didn't have an event. It's actually better to have them afterwards as well -- that takes some careful analysis; as you note, you don't actually have event data then, but you can analyse the bias either way and it's smaller with control times after the event time as long as the event  is rare and you actually have the exposure data.  It's in the appendix of the paper I linked. There's also a recent paper in *Biometrics* on causal estimation in this design.